# TYPO3: What does dependency injection actually do and why do i need the following code?

Tags: dependency-injection, typo3

A little question to understand TYPO3 better:

In my controller i have following code:

```
 /**
     * applianceRepository
     *
     * @var \Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Repository\ApplianceRepository
     * 
     * @inject
     */
    protected $applianceRepository = null;
```

It's about this whole dependency injection... Is it correct to assume that the injection fetches the dependencies from my TCA file for that specific class? Or what does the dependency injection actually do? From what i understand the connection to the tables in the MySQL database only happens when the following code is executed:

```
 public function listAction()
    {
        $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
        $apprep = $objectManager->get(\Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Repository\ApplianceRepository::class);
        $appliances = $apprep->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('appliances', $appliances);
}
```

So what actually does the dependency injection do and why is it necessary?

Edit: As an additional question... What does the following code do or rather "Why do i need the notation in the comments block?".

```
 /**
     * action show
     *
     * @param \Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Appliance $appliance
     * @return void
     */
    public function showAction(\Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Appliance $appliance)
    {
        $this->view->assign('appliance', $appliance);
    }
```

I've already defined the parameter in the function, so why the comments block? I know it's necessary, but i never understood why.

Comment: Could you make a new question out of your edit? Because it doesn't have to do anything with the original question and an explanation could take some lines of writing, not suited for a comment.

Comment: As there is now a new question for the second part, you should remove it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency injection has nothing to do with TCA or the database. It isn't even a thing of TYPO3 itself, but a concept TYPO3 uses to inject instances of other objects, available in the outside world of your class, into your class/object at runtime.
It basically is comparable with a class, whichs constructor defines parameters of objects that it needs.
So one could argue that the `@inject` annotation is nothing different then something like this:

```
class SomeController {
    /**
     * @var SomeClass
     * @inject
     */
    protected $someClassDependency;
}

// this is equal to

class SomeController {
    protected $someClassDependency;
    public function __construct(SomeClass $someClassDependency) {
        $this->someClassDependency = $someClassDependency;
    }
}

// and also equal to

class SomeController {
    protected $someClassDependency;
    public function injectSomeClassDependency(SomeClass $someClassDependency) {
        $this->someClassDependency = $someClassDependency;
    }
}
```

The main thing about this injection is the automated process that is detecting which objects need to be injected when TYPO3 constructs an instance of the class via their internal `GeneralUtility::makeInstance` method.
There will be a check for all `@inject` annotations, TYPO3 then inserts inject-methods, like the one in my code example, into a newly generated PHP code of your class. It then executes that "updated" PHP code of your class and on instanciation of your class's object, all methods that start with `inject` will be checked for what they expect as parameters. The corresponding objects of the parameter types class will be collected if they exist or instances of the classes will be created and given to the inject-methods, thus providing ready to use objects for your class.

Comment: Thank you... This makes it much better to understand than described in the TYPO3 documentation.

Comment: Something that still confuses me: The first code example injects an object of the type appliancerepository... But the second code example (where u instanciate an object of the same class via the objectmanager) seems to work even without previously injecting the object. So is dependency injetion not really a requirement when working with controllers in TYPO3 extensions?

Comment: Dependency injection via the annotation, put simply, did exactly what the second example with the ObjectManager did, but instead of you having to get the ObjectManager and instanciating the repository yourself, TYPO3 does this for you and gives the ready-to-use object to your controller. So, no there is no need for using dependency injections at all, but it rather is a question of convenience

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both. If you supply the @inject annotation, it will automatically be instantiated for you (as in your example):

```
/**
 * applianceRepository
 *
 * @var \Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Repository\ApplianceRepository
 * 
 * @inject
 */
 protected $applianceRepository;


 ...
 $this->applianceRepository->findAll();
```

---

An alternative is to do it this way:

```
/**
 * @param \Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Repository\ApplianceRepository $applianceRepository
 */ 
public function injectApplianceRepository($applianceRepository)
{
    $this->applianceRepository = $applianceRepository;
}
```

The reason you may want to do this are performance reasons as mentioned by several people. If performance is not an issue for you, you can safely ignore this and use the @inject annotation.